# Python Web-scraping Solution

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, I'm new to python and am trying to develop an exercise in which I scrape the page numbers from a list on this url, which is a list of various published papers.

When I go into the HTML element for the page I want to scrape, I inspect the element and find this HTML code to match up:

```
<div class="src">
        Foreign Affairs, Vol. 79, No. 4 (Jul. - Aug., 2000), pp. 53-63
    </div>
```

The part that I want to churn out what is in between the class brackets.
This is what I attempted to write in order to do the job.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.jstor.org/action/doAdvancedSearch?c4=AND&c5=AND&q2=&pt=&q1=nuclear&f3=all&f1=all&c3=AND&c6=AND&q6=&f4=all&q4=&f0=all&c2=AND&q3=&acc=off&c1=AND&isbn=&q0=china+&f6=all&la=&f2=all&ed=2001&q5=&f5=all&group=none&sd=2000"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links = soup.find_all("div class='src'")
for link in links:
    print
```

I know that this code is unfinished and that's because I don't know where to go from here :/. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: You want the tag text? Like: "Foreign Affairs, Vol. 79, No. 4 (Jul. - Aug., 2000), pp. 53-63" ?

Comment: Tip: [Check the sites terms](http://about.jstor.org/terms) **Prohibited Uses of the Content.** (d) undertake any activity such as the use of computer programs that automatically download or export Content, commonly known as web robots, spiders, crawlers, wanderers or accelerators that may interfere with, disrupt or otherwise burden the JSTOR server(s)

Comment: Did you actually  try to read the documentation?  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the pages inside all divs with class="src"

If so, then you need to do:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.jstor.org/action/doAdvancedSearch?c4=AND&c5=AND&q2=&pt=&q1=nuclear&f3=all&f1=all&c3=AND&c6=AND&q6=&f4=all&q4=&f0=all&c2=AND&q3=&acc=off&c1=AND&isbn=&q0=china+&f6=all&la=&f2=all&ed=2001&q5=&f5=all&group=none&sd=2000"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'src'})
for link in links:
    pages = re.search('(pp.\s*\d*-\d*)', link.text)
    print pages.group(1)
```

Note that I have used regex to get the page numbers. This may sound strange for people unfamiliar with regular expressions, but I think its more elegant than using string operations like `strip` and `split`

Comment: Oh, this is perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: If I only wanted to print a segment of that string of text (say "pp.  53-63") how would I write that into the code?

Comment: you could do print link.text[-9:] if this information is always in the end of the string

Comment: edited to include a good way for you to get the pages with regex

Comment: More elegant than `text.rsplit(None, 1)[1]`?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Tales Pádua's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539709/189134) is this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="src">
    Foreign Affairs, Vol. 79, No. 4 (Jul. - Aug., 2000), pp. 53-63
</div>
<div class="src">
    Other Book, Vol. 1, No. 1 (Jul. - Aug., 2000), pp. 1-23
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "src")
for link in links:
    print link.text.strip()
```

This outputs:

```
Foreign Affairs, Vol. 79, No. 4 (Jul. - Aug., 2000), pp. 53-63
Other Book, Vol. 1, No. 1 (Jul. - Aug., 2000), pp. 1-23
```

This answer uses the `class_` parameter, which is [recommended](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) in the documentation.

---

If you are looking to get the page number, and everything follows the format above (comma separated), you can change the for loop to grab the last element of the string:

```
print link.text.split(",")[-1].strip()
```

This outputs:

```
pp. 53-63
pp. 1-23
```

Comment: `class_` is recommended for a  css classes i.e `div class="foo bar"`.